# wrong output simple tax calculator

Tags: c++, math

I need help the ttlTx variable displays as 0 in the output on Bloodshed though I passed the code through ideone and it seemed to work, is it the data type maybe? help appreciated!

```
/*


*/
//Libraries
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Global Constants

//Functioning Prototypes

//Execution Begins Here
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //Variables
    float purchse, ttlTx, stateTx, cntyTx, total;

    //Process
    purchse= 52;
    stateTx= 0.04; //state tax
    cntyTx= 0.02; //county tax
    ttlTx= purchse*(stateTx + cntyTx); //total tax
    total = purchse+ttlTx;

    //output
    cout<<"the total tax on a $"<< purchse<<" is $"<<
        ttlTx<<endl;
    cout<<"which brings the total to $" << total<<endl;

    //Exit Stage Right
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Bloodshed? what's that?

Comment: Bloodshed Dev-C++, an IDE - see http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html.

Comment: i'm sorry I meant DEV-C++, Bloodshed is the name of the software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the *code* you've pasted, under my `gcc` compiler, I get:

```
the total tax on a $52 is $3.12
which brings the total to $55.12
```

as expected.

Since DevC++ uses MinGW, it's also using the `gcc` compiler and I can't imagine any version greater than 0.1 that would have had a bug that severe :-)

Hence it's almost certainly an environmental problem of some description. DevC++ is also not as active or well supported (though this is my opinion) as some other IDEs so I tend to either suggest people use CygWin (if they don't care about an IDE) or [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (if they do).

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine. I think something wrong with your ID. No error in the programe.

[image]